# Setting up root controller

Tags: php, frameworks, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I copied routes from Silverstripe 4 alpha 6 to 4.0 project, and root controller stopped working. All I've got is that "Welcome to SilverStripe" page, no matter what I type in routes. I use framework only, downloaded zip file.

If I try to add route other than '' (empty one), and other than that noted in root/core routes, it works, but it seems that I cannot override those that are in. Tried with before/after in routes.yml also.

I even tried copying whole routes file from [documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/controllers/routing/), but no luck. Tried with namespaced controller and plain PHP class. Again, nothing happened.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to make things clear, I flushed the cache numerous times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out solution - in related question for aliasing Security/login.

All I need to do is to set routes to be after everything:

```
After: '*'
```